# How to declare, insert and iterate a php associative array with an associative array as value?

Tags: php, arrays, hashmap

I need to work with a hashtable which values can store variables like:

- `$numberOfItems`
- `$ItemsNames`

If I ain't wrong, that would mean another hash like array as value.

What should be the right syntax for inserting and iterating over it?

Is anything like:

```
$hash['anyKey']=>$numberOfItems=15;
$hash['anyKey']=>$ItemsNames=['f','fw'];
```

valid?

Comment: Why would you store the number of elements separately, when you could just easily get the correct number with `count()`? And please make a more elaborate example of what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if there's no chance to have collusion in item name, you can use the name in key

```
$hash[$ItemsName] = $numberOfItems;
```

in the other case, use an integer for example as a key, then the different "attributes" you want as keys for the 2nd array

```
$hash[$integer]["count"] = $numberOfItems;
$hash[$integer]["name"] = $name;$
```

Then, for iterating (1st case):

```
 foreach ($hash as $name => $number) {
       echo $number;
       echo $name;
   }
```

or, 2nd case

```
foreach ($hash as $item) {
       echo $item["name"];
       echo $item["count"];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To create php array, which can be a hash table, you can do:

```
$arr['element'] = $item;
$arr['element'][] = $item;
$arr['element'][]['element'] = $item;
```

Other way:

```
$arr = array('element' => array('element' => array(1)));
```

To iterate over it use foreach loop:

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
}
```

It's also possible to create nested loops.

About your case:

```
$hash['anyKey']=>$numberOfItems=15;
$hash['anyKey']=>$ItemsNames=['f','fw'];
```

I would do:

```
$hash['anyKey']['numberOfItems'] = 15;
$hash['anyKey']['ItemsNames'] = array('f','fw');
```

Comment: What if I need to push anything to `$hash['anyKey']['ItemsNames']`?

Comment: `$hash['anyKey']['ItemsNames'][] = 'some new value';` `[]` will create new numeric incremental key.

Comment: No, I mean, if you declare `$hash['anyKey']['ItemsNames'] = array('f','fw');` How can I make such array to be `('f','fw', 'zz')` later

Comment: `$hash['anyKey']['ItemsNames'][] = 'zz';`